# Exception while batch processing document with Google Cloud DocumentAI V1 - StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-dotnet-client, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to create PoC for Google Cloud DocumentAI V1 using [this](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.DocumentAI.V1/latest)

I am using DocAI to convert .pdf files into text using DocAI BatchProcessing. I have created console application with below code, which is working fine with single document. But when I try to process multiple pdf documents it's throwing exception,

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded",
> Detail="Deadline Exceeded",
> DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException:
> {"created":"@1650465671.748000000","description":"Deadline
> Exceeded","file":"......\src\core\ext\filters\deadline\deadline_filter.cc","file_line":81,"grpc_status":4}")'

[image]

Application Code:

```
public static class DocAIBatchProcess
{
    const string projectId = "PROJECTID"; 
    const string processorId = "PROCESSID";
    const string location = "us";
    const string gcsInputBucketName = "BUCKETNAME";
    const string gcsOutputBucketName = "gs://BUCKETNAME/OUTPUTFOLDER/";
    const string gcsOutputUriPrefix = "PREFIX";
    const string prefix = "INPUTFOLDER/";
    const string delimiter = "/";

    public static bool BatchProcessDocument(this IEnumerable<GCPStorage.Object> storageObjects)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Processing documents started...");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------");

            DocumentProcessorServiceClient documentProcessorServiceClient = DocumentProcessorServiceClient.Create();
            string name = $"projects/{projectId}/locations/{location}/processors/{processorId}";

            GcsDocument gcsDocument = null;
            GcsDocuments gcsDocuments = new GcsDocuments();
            var storage = StorageClient.Create();
            foreach (var storageObject in storageObjects)
            {
                if (storageObject.Name != prefix)
                {
                    gcsDocument = new GcsDocument()
                    {
                        GcsUri = $"gs://gcsInputBucketName/{storageObject.Name}",
                        MimeType = "application/pdf"
                    };
                    gcsDocuments.Documents.Add(gcsDocument);
                }
            }

            //Input Config
            BatchDocumentsInputConfig inputConfig = new BatchDocumentsInputConfig();
            inputConfig.GcsDocuments = gcsDocuments;

            //Output Config
            var fullGcsPath = $"gs://{gcsOutputBucketName}/{gcsOutputUriPrefix}/";
            GcsOutputConfig gcsOutputConfig = new GcsOutputConfig();
            gcsOutputConfig.GcsUri = gcsOutputBucketName;

            DocumentOutputConfig documentOutputConfig = new DocumentOutputConfig();
            documentOutputConfig.GcsOutputConfig = gcsOutputConfig;

            // Configure the batch process request.
            BatchProcessRequest batchProcessRequest = new BatchProcessRequest();
            batchProcessRequest.Name = name;
            batchProcessRequest.InputDocuments = inputConfig;
            batchProcessRequest.DocumentOutputConfig = documentOutputConfig;

            // Make the request
            Operation<BatchProcessResponse, BatchProcessMetadata> response = documentProcessorServiceClient.BatchProcessDocuments(batchProcessRequest);                
            // Poll until the returned long-running operation is complete
            Operation<BatchProcessResponse, BatchProcessMetadata> completedResponse = response.PollUntilCompleted();
            
            // Retrieve the operation result
            BatchProcessResponse result = completedResponse.Result;
    }
}
```

**DeadlineExceeded : "Deadline expired before operation could complete."**

I tried looking into documentation but couldn't find anything concreate. If someone knows about why this is happening ? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello. Can you let me know - 1. How many documents are you trying to process? 2. Have you tried overriding the default timeout setting?

Comment: To change the default timeout settings, please refer to this [code sample](https://gist.github.com/kabilanmohanraj/28af5b90586637442482dcb4870aeafe). Let me know if extending the timeout works.

Comment: Hello @KabilanMohanraj, I am trying 3 documents for processing and the size of each document.
doc1 => 110 kb => 3 pages
doc2 => 473 kb => 2 pages
doc3 => 13 kb => 1 pages

Comment: I tried requests with multiple documents and multi-page documents and they worked as expected. Can you please try extending the timeout?

Comment: Yes, I did tried few days back with CallSettings but its throwing different error and I am not sure whether this is something related to network! Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1650914549.415000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3159,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1650914549.415000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":

Comment: that's network issue, my network team just put me out of firewall and it worked without any issue. thanks @KabilanMohanraj for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is related to network firewall for me. my network team just put me out of firewall and it worked without any issue. thanks